# How to Cut Off String After Some Special Symbol is Encountered

Tags: python, django

I have `message = 'This is a private post. Cc: @me, @you.and @others,too. I @hope>this is okay'`

I extracted words that `startswith('@')` symbol after iterating through `message.split(' ')`.

This yielded `mentions = ['@me', '@you.and', '@others,too', '@hope>this']` which is not what I want.

The desired result is `mentions = ['@me', '@you', '@others', '@hope']`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> x = 'This is a private post. Cc: @me, @you.and @others,too. I @hope>this is okay'
>>> [re.search(r'(@\w+)', z).groups()[0] for z in x.split() if z.startswith('@')]
['@me', '@you', '@others', '@hope']
```

Comment: this will find words that have @ in the middle of the words also

Comment: This works but how do I replace it back to their position is `x` after tampering with them?

Comment: @linuxfan: The first answer is exactly what I have looking for.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks for spotting that. Updated the code snippet first split the entire string and then search for the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "This is a private post. Cc: @me, @you.and @others,too. I @hope>this is okay"
>>> re.findall(r"(@\w+)\b", s)
['@me', '@you', '@others', '@hope']
```